# Alias for paths not working in typescript with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a reactjs app with typescript. I am trying to make alias work. Here is my code for tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@/assets/*": ["./assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

My webpack configuration is as follow

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
      '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, 'types'),
    },
  },
};
```

I get this error when i run the app on localhost

```
ERROR in ./src/presentation/login/index.tsx 4:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/src/components/screen' in 'xxxxx/src/presentation/login'
```

There is no error in console and when i click on the @/src/components/screen it does take me to correct file so its something only in localhost.

How can I fix this

Comment: Try changing webpack alias to match tsconfig path exactly: `'@/src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),`. Then when importing your component, try `@/components/screen` since `/src` is already in the base path.

Comment: that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

The config file you've attached looks like a rule for SVG modules, not the full config.

I suppose you've accidentally added your aliases as part of an SVG loader rule instead of placing them at the very root of your config.

Instead of this:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        resolve: {
          alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
            '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, 'types'),
          },
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You should have something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
      '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, 'types'),
    },
  },
}
```

Links to Webpack docs:

- [This is global resolution aliases that're gonna be applied to all imports in your project](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias);
- [This is module resolution, where you can also specify aliases, but they'll be applied only for a specific module type](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleresolve).